# Spring boot , Spring data JPA concurrent access

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, concurrency, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am trying to create a Restful API with Spring boot and Spring data JPA to do the CRUD operations. The database will be Oracle relational database.Now for concurrent access , If we only use spring transactions using @Transactional, will that serve our purpose of concurrent CRUD operations.

I see there are JPA Optimistic and pessimistic locking strategy version column. My specific question is , for concurrent CRUD operations do we need both Spring transactions and JPA locking strategy? OR only configuring Spring transactions accordingly will be sufficient?

Comment: It depends on how you want your application to behave in the presence of concurrent CRUD operations.

Comment: Thanks @JensSchauder. What we want is multiple users can come and do concurrent CRUD operations.  Can we achieve the same thing using either Spring tranasactions OR JPA Optimistic locking. Or Do we need to configure both spring transactions and JPA locking.

Comment: I understood your question so far. But what do you actually want to happen if two users/processes try to change the same entity at the same time? Throw an exception? Apply one change the the other, overwriting the first? Blocking one until the other is finished? 

Let alone questions like what should happen if someone edits an `Order` while someone else adds and `OrderItem` to the same entity?

Comment: @JensSchauder if two processes are trying to change the same entity at the same time, I want one to be blocked untill other is finished. Can this be achieved via spring transactions only.

Answer (score 12):

Try to start with the following simple approach that IMO will be suitable in many cases: [Optimistic locking](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-optimistic) with [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry).

1) Add `version` property annotated with `@Version` to your entities (you can do it in base abstract entity class, for example, to simplify the process):

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    // other stuff
}
```

In this case when you, for example, will update your entity then Hibernate will use the current value of `version` property in condition clause of update query, and increment this value to store the entity with it. For example this code of some service:

```java
@Transactional
public Optional<MyEntity> update(Long id, MyEntity source) {
    return myEntityRepository
           .findById(id)
           .map(target -> mapper.updateEntity(source, target));
}
```

will generate the following SQL queries:

```sql
1. select * from my_entities where id = ?; 
2. update my_entities set ..., version = <version value from query #1> + 1 where id = ? and version = <version value from query #1>;
```

So if another concurrent process manages to update this entity first, then your method fails with an exception (OptimisticLockException).

2) To manage to exceptions in that method, add `@Retryable` annotation to it (and `@EnableRetry` annotation on your config or application class):

```java
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 2)
@Transactional
public Optional<MyEntity> update(Long id, MyEntity source) {
    // ...
}
```

In this case, if an exception rises in that method it will be called again in a new transaction to repeat the operation.

Additional info:

- [Optimistic Locking in JPA](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking)
- [Guide to Spring Retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)
- [My Spring Retry demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-retry-demo)

Answer (score 1):

Optimistic lock is default strategy of JPA. Optimistic locking is can be used for most of the applications. Optimistic lock is much more easier and efficient. Pessimistic lock need to be used in cases like, where you need to know Collision before committing your transaction.

So you do not need to configure a locking strategy.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmet Amasyali. So this means only configuring spring transactions properly will help us to achieve desired concurrency behavior i.e. concurrent CRUD operations.

Comment: @adiCool Yes. For most cases optimistic lock should be enough.

Comment: But I came across some references which says LockModeType.NONE is default. I guess when you use EntityManager.find(Class, Object) the default LockModeType is used.